# creating triggers in sql server script

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger for insert on a table :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [General].[trg_Extr_Tab1_Insert] 
   ON  [General].[Extr_Tab1] 
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 

BEGIN
declare @nExtractions int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
begin try   
    set @nExtractions = (select count(*) from General.Extr_Tab1 )
    create table #Extr
    (
      Extr1 int
    )
.....
```

the trigger gets added to the table (Extr_Tab1) and works fine .
Since I have many tables like Extr_Tab1 (Extr_Tab1, Extr_Tab2 ... Extr_Tabn) I want to create a trigger for each one of these tables. Having a script which creates the database and the tables , I wanted to add the scripts for creating the triggers in the general script, right after the creation of the tables.
But when i run the general script, I get  a :

*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.*

right on the first "CREATE TRIGGER " line .
The code for creating the trigger has been generated automatically on Sql Server : I took the code, which was working fine , and duplicated it just changing the table names :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [General].[trg_Extr_Tabn_Insert] 
   ON  [General].[Extr_Tabn] 
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
declare @nExtractions int;
create  table #Extr (   Extr1 int   )
....
```

Moreover, I am using temp tables in the script (#Extr) , but it seems even if it is defined each time in the respective trigger's scope, whenever the script defines it I get an error :

*There is already an object named '#Extr' in the database.*

like if the definition of the temp table is global no matter if it is defined in the scope of the trigger

Comment: You need to actually show us your script and tbh this sounds like an XY-problem and a poor design.

Comment: The script is way too long so I guess I can reduce it to the essentials :